# Dynamic dropdown list and its options using javascript in table row?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

How to add a dropdown list and its options in table row dynamically using javascript. The function needs to be called is Onclick of button.

```
function addRow() {                                                                 
        @{

            Model.lstfcDayConfig.Add(new NewFCDayConfig());               
         }
        var index = $("#tbFCDays").children("tr").length;                                                                      
        var indexCell = "<td style='display:none'><input  name='lstfcDayConfig.Index' type='hidden' value='" + index + "' /></td>";
        var titleCell = "<td><input id='lstfcDayConfig" + index + "__Title' name='lstfcDayConfig[" + index + "].Description' type='text' value='' /></td>";
        var startDateTimeCell = "<td><input id='lstfcDayConfig" + index + "__StartTime' name='lstfcDayConfig[" + index + "].StartDateTime' type='date' value='' /></td>";
        var EndDateTimeCell = "<td><input id='lstfcDayConfig" + index + "__EndTime' name='lstfcDayConfig[" + index + "].EndDateTime' type='date' value='' /></td>";
        var removeCell = "<td><input id='btnAddDay' type='button' value='Remove' onclick='removeRow(" + index + ");' /></td>";

        var newRow = "<tr id='trFCConfigRow" + index + "'>" +
        indexCell + titleCell + startDateTimeCell + EndDateTimeCell + removeCell + "</tr>";
        $("#tbFCDays").append(newRow);
    }
```

I have added textbox using the above code but i am not sure how to add dropdown
Using select box i can add dropdown in the same code but problem comes when i need to add options as options need to be added from ViewBag

Comment: Can you give an example of what you have tried already? This isn't really a place to come for people to write code for you, but if you have something that we can build off of, we can help you get pointed in the right direction or show you where there may be issues in your code.

Comment: what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out myself. Posting here who might need it...

```
function addRow() {                                                                 
        @{

            Model.lstObjEvtNotifyCfgDetail.Add(new  NewEventNotifyCfgDetail());               
        }


    var index = $("#tbEvtCfg").children("tr").length;


    var indexCell = "<td style='display:none'><input name='lstObjEvtNotifyCfgDetail.Index' type='hidden' value='" + index + "' /></td>";
    //var titleCell = "<td><input id='lstObjEvtNotifyCfgDetail" + index + "__Title' name='lstObjEvtNotifyCfgDetail[" + index + "].EventCode' type='text' value='' /></td>";

    //var startDateTimeCell = "<td><input id='lstfcDayConfig" + index + "__StartTime' name='lstfcDayConfig[" + index + "].StartDateTime' type='date' value='' /></td>";
    //var EndDateTimeCell = "<td><input id='lstfcDayConfig" + index + "__EndTime' name='lstfcDayConfig[" + index + "].EndDateTime' type='date' value='' /></td>";
    //var removeCell = "<td><input id='btnAddDay' type='button' value='Remove' onclick='removeRow(" + index + ");' /></td>";

     var EventCodeControl="<td>"+ "<select name='lstObjEvtNotifyCfgDetail[" + index + "].EventCode' value=''>" ;


     @foreach (SelectListItem sli in (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.EventCodeList)
     {
         @:EventCodeControl = EventCodeControl + "<Option Value=@(sli.Value)>" + '@sli.Text' + "</Option>";
     }
        EventCodeControl = EventCodeControl + "</select></td>";

     var NotifyHanControl = "<td>" + "<input type='checkbox' name='lstObjEvtNotifyCfgDetail[" + index + "].IsNotifyHAN'>" + "</td>";
     var NotifyWanControl = "<td>" + "<input type='checkbox' name='lstObjEvtNotifyCfgDetail[" + index + "].IsNotifyWan'>" + "</td>";
     var DiscSupplyControl = "<td>" + "<input type='checkbox' name='lstObjEvtNotifyCfgDetail[" + index + "].IsDisconnectSupply'>" + "</td>";

    var newRow = "<tr id='trFCConfigRow" + index + "'>" +
    indexCell + EventCodeControl +NotifyHanControl+ NotifyWanControl+DiscSupplyControl+"</tr>";
    $("#tbEvtCfg").append(newRow);
    }
```

Happy Coding!!!!!